# MSSQL manager like phpMyAdmin

Tags: looking-for-a-script, .net, sql-server

I have a .net hosting account but they have provided a free asp.net enterprise manager, a software to manage MSSQL server. Is there any other Phpmyadmin like software. My server supports Php also.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372641/something-like-phpmyadmin-but-for-sql-server

Answer (score 1):

[HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/) now offers support for MsSQL

Answer (score 0):

phpMyAdmin is a web based tool for mySQL Administration. So what is HeidiSQL doing in this thread dear John?

Also the installation of xampp or wamp wouldn't help as they support mysql stuff and not mssql (phpmyadmin = mysql and not mssql).

The only answer I can give you, google for a solution that fits your needs. Sadly there's not really a good free tool available (thanks microsoft for not creating a web based administration for mssql!!).

- SQL Web Data Admin (last update 2009?): http://sqlwebadmin.codeplex.com/
- myLittleAdmin (much too expensive): http://mylittleadmin.com/en/purchase.aspx
- PHP Query Analyze (looks like it has not quite much options to go with... Mainly for running own queries, but I haven't tested it!): https_sourceforge.net_projects_phpqueryanalyze

Answer (score -1):

I this you could try downloading XAMPP or WAMP. They're both PHP testing servers and supports also PHPMyAdmin which would help you managing your database. :))

Comment: This doesn't answer their question at all